# Jquery see if div has class error or not

Tags: jquery

How to check if my div has class A and B or has class A B and C 
I want to do something like

```
if my div is <div class="form-group field-post-file">
// Do some code 
if my div is <div class="form-group field-post-file has-error">
// Don't do anything
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasClass()` method to achive this:-

```js
if ($("#div1").hasClass("form-group field-post-file")) {
  console.log('div1');
}
if ($("#div2").hasClass("form-group field-post-file has-error")) {
 console.log('div2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group field-post-file" id="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error" id="div2">DIV 2</div>
```

Alternate with 1 div:-

```js
if ($("#div1").hasClass("form-group field-post-file has-error")) {
  console.log('div1 with form-group field-post-file has-error');
}
else if ($("#div1").hasClass("form-group field-post-file")) {
  console.log('div1 with form-group field-post-file');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error" id="div1">DIV 1</div>
```

Comment: it's almost the right answer but for me is only one div, so I want to know if the div has error or not; if my div class is form-group field-post-file or it is form-group field-post-file has-error, is the same div with id  div1

Comment: @Bynd check my alternative answer

Comment: Thank you so much the alternative answer is the best solution, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The method [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) should do what you are looking for.

```js
$('.form-group.field-post-file').each((i, e) => {
  let $e = $(e);

  // guard to exclude elements with class 'has-error'
  if ($e.hasClass('has-error')) return;
  
  console.log($e.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group field-post-file">div #1</div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error">div #2</div>
```

Alternatively you could just have excluded the class with the selector in the first place.

```js
$('.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)').each((i, e) => {
  let $e = $(e);
  
  console.log($e.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group field-post-file">div #1</div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error">div #2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer that does, indeed, answer your question I felt it worth offering a couple of alternatives, since the use of an `if` can be avoided by the use of a simple selector, both in jQuery and with 'plain' JavaScript.

While you specify you have only one `<div>` element to check, I'll offer alternatives – in JavaScript – that will allow for one, or multiple elements.

In both approaches, though, we use the same CSS selector:

```
// we first select all the <div> elements with the classes
// of 'form-group' and 'field-post-file', and then we use the
// negation pseudo-class of ':not()' to remove those elements
// that have the class of '.has-error':
div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)
```

First, jQuery:

```
$('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)').css('color', 'limegreen');
```

```js
$('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)').css('color', 'limegreen');
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lb930hqm/).

In JavaScript the following will select only the first – of any – matches:

```
document.querySelector('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)')
  .style
  .color = 'limegreen';
```

```js
document.querySelector('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)')
  .style
  .color = 'limegreen';
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lb930hqm/1/).

This will cause an [error if there is no element matching the supplied selector](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lb930hqm/2/), so one way of preventing that error is to use an `if`:

```
let elem = document.querySelector('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)');
if (elem) {
  elem.style.color = 'limegreen';
}
```

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)');
if (elem) {
  elem.style.color = 'limegreen';
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lb930hqm/3/).

But as the use of an appropriate selector was to avoid using an `if` in the first place, this option isn't ideal. The following approach, though, prevents an error if no match is found and also allows for multiple matches to be found:

```
// here we find the same element(s) as before:
document.querySelectorAll('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)')

  // we then take advantage of NodeList.forEach() to iterate over every
  // Node in the NodeList; because we're iterating over that NodeList
  // there is no error if no nodes are found:
  .forEach(

    // here we use Arrow function syntax to pass the current Node
    // of the NodeList ('match') to the anonymous function which
    // sets the 'color' of the current Node to 'limegreen':
    (match) => match.style.color = 'limegreen'
  )
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)').forEach(
  (match) => match.style.color = 'limegreen'
);
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lb930hqm/4/).

In the event that you, or your users, are using a browser that doesn't implement `NodeList.forEach()` then this can be rewritten as follows:

```
// here we call Array.prototype.forEach and, with
// Function.prototype.call(), apply that method to the
// NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)'),

  // a browser that doesn't support NodeList.forEach() probably doesn't
  // support Arrow functions, so here we use a regular anonymous function
  // in place of the Arrow function from earlier:
  function(match) {
    match.style.color = 'limegreen';
  });
```

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('div.form-group.field-post-file:not(.has-error)'),
  function(match) {
    match.style.color = 'limegreen';
  });
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em 0;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file has-error"></div>
<div class="form-group field-post-file"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yw175bqd/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).